# Convert MySQL Unix Time Stamp to Human Readble Form

Tags: mysql

Appreciate that this topic has been covered many times and I have tried all the combinations I can find without success.

The following timestamp is an example of that returned when using rpt_default_day.time_stamp:

1474502400000

If I put this time stamp into the following website it returns the correct date and time:

http://www.epochconverter.com/

Below are some examples of queries I have been using:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('rpt_default_day.time_stamp'), '%e %b %Y') AS 'Date',
FROM_UNIXTIME('rpt_default_day.time_stamp') AS 'Date', 
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('rpt_default_day.time_stamp')) AS 'Date',
```

Problem is whatever I do I'm always getting returned the epoch time of:

'1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000'

Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: You don't suppose that the definition of `rpt_default_day.time_stamp` might be a bit pertinent to the question?  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove three zeros from your string and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciated and straight to the point. Here is how I did it from_unixtime(cast(rpt_default_day.time_stamp AS char(10))), perhaps not the best way but it worked.

Comment: No, @mflammia.  Please... no.  You have a timestamp in milliseconds, while `FROM_UNIXTIME()` expects time in seconds.  Do the right thing and divide the value by 1000.  Do not truncate it with a cast. `FROM_UNIXTIME(rpt_default_day.time_stamp / 1000)`

Comment: Understood. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A proper format values should be passed as a parameter to "FROM_UNIXTIME" function :

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) as ts, 
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x') as f_tm;
+------------+-----------------------------------+
| ts         | f_tm                              |
+------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1474755927 | 2016 25th September 01:25:27 2016 |
+------------+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

possible format values are specified in the [Mysql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)